# Resizable and flexible input form

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap and can not figure out how to make the input form that would have been flexible and zoomed-out, that is, when I reduce the form it should not only be reduced in width, and height - so should decrease the font size, unfortunately I do not understand how to do this without using js. Maybe someone has an idea or this functionality is initially available in the css framework?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the responsiveness part of the bootstrap document
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: I read the documentation several times, it's not quite right. I want to know how to do an automatic resize the font